# NLTK Parts Of Speech Tag is considering "apps" and "please" as verbs?

Tags: nlp

Problem statement: lemmatize those words which are verbs.

Text:

> ['I would love to try or hear the sample audio your app can produce.',
> "I do not want to purchase, because I've purchased so many apps that
> say they do something and do not deliver.",  "Can you please add audio
> samples with text you've converted?",  "I'd love to see the end
> results.",  'Thanks!']

Code for `POS`:

```
tokenized_word=nltk.word_tokenize(str(file))
postag=nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_word)


def pos_tagger(nltk_tag):
    if nltk_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    else:
        return None
wt=list(map(lambda x: (x[0],pos_tagger(x[1])), postag))
```

But it is also picking up *apps* and *please* as verbs, since the POS-tags of these are coming out as `("apps","VBP")` , `("please","VB")`.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do. The NLTK POS Tagger is a stochastic tagger, and (like any tagger) it makes mistakes. While *please* can be a verb, *apps* only looks like one, so I suspect it is not in the tagger's dictionary. If the training data is older, *apps* might not have been in common use when it was created.

If you have certain words which are frequently tagged wrongly, you could add them to a list and filter them out in a post-processing step. That is what I have done in a similar situation.